# How to perform Signout redirection to a desired location in Spree SessionsController in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, spree

```
Spree::UserSessionsController.class_eval do
   include Spree::AuthenticationHelpers
     def new
     end

     def create
        authenticate_spree_user!

       if spree_user_signed_in?
        redirect_to main_app.userregistration_new_path
      else
        render :new
      end
  end

end
```

I got above method defination from spree_auth_devise sessionscontroller implementation. Hopefully I have got access to spree_current_user. 
Next, I am trying to implement the signout, infact i am able to signout with simple call to 
     **spree_logout_path**
But I want to change the redirection after signout. unable to find any specific action declaration for signout..

How to perform this signout along with a different routes redirection in rails  + Spree ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protected

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    root_path # change this to where you want to redirect after sign out
  end

end
```